# Индексация БД

Tags: база-данных, sql

Подскажите, как правильно и стоит ли создавать индекс для таблиц?

Comment: Все зависит от решаемой задачи/проблемы. Вы можете подробнее описать ситуацию ?

Comment: Однощначного ответа нет и быть не может, индексация ускоряет выборку но замедляет обновление и добавление новых записей...

Comment: в большинстве практических задач скорость выборки важнее скорости изменения (оно обычно выполняется над единичными записями)

Comment: не скажите, БД бывают разные...

Comment: да мне надо было общие практические принципы, синтаксис и тд, а тут я уже экспериментами буду смотреть, ускорит или нет, так как реально бд разные бывают и вчера слышал историю, как запрос на оракле начал выполнятся быстрее только из-за перестановки условий выборки

Comment: Могу посоветовать замечательную книгу [Рефакторинг SQL-приложений](http://www.books.ru/books/refaktoring-sql-prilozheniy-645320/). Почерпнете много полезного про производительность (в том числе и про индексы).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

обычно индексы создаются для ускорения выборки из таблички.. 
Индексируется, чаще всего, поле таблицы, по которому происходит выборка..

Как создать индекс в mysql можно поитать [тут](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

(не стоит забвать что индексы увеличивают время инсертов и апдейтов)

Comment: пасиб, то что надо =)